# How to install python modules automatically with a single scripts

Tags: python, shell

I have build a Python module for machine learning and prediction proposes it included about 9 different scripts, which require various dependencies like scikit-learn, pandas, PyDpi etc. now.

As this programme specifically developed for biologist and i am expecting that end users of this software  would not fully aware with the Linux system and the installation process. I wish to include  a script with this package that  automatically install all the dependencies prior to use. 
is there any way for this ? please suggest.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Google for `python distutils`

Comment: I'd also recommend taking a look at `virtualenv` (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/). It basically enables making isolated Python environments where you can install any packages without touching system files. The end users may not even be allowed to install any software (or have permissions to `sudo`), so you could provide them with a script that creates a virtualenv for running your scripts. It is fairly simple to use, e.g. `virtualenv py` to create and then `py/bin/python` to run, or  `py/bin/pip install package` to install to the virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an installation setup script using Distutils, which automatically loads required dependencies. Here is the guide how to do that https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html

Example setup.py file:

```
try:
  from setuptools import setup, find_packages
except ImportError:
  from distutils.core import setup


setup(name='myLib',
  version='1.0',
  description='my great lib',
  author='Author name',
  author_email='author@mail.com',
  packages = find_packages(),       
  install_requires = ['docutils>=0.3'],
  )
```

When installing your package, user just needs to type

```
python setup.py install
```

which automatically installs needed dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using pip

```
import pip

def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])
```

For example

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    install('pandas')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use pip freeze and write all requirements in a txt file like:

```
reportlab==3.0
djang0==1.8.4
...
```

save it in a file name requirements.txt

then run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```